# Why isn't my Go Reader working?

Tags: go

I tried to implement a very trivial `io.Reader` in Go:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

// Very trivial function I implemented.
func (r *rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return 5, nil // Return some trivial values for now.
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader(
        "Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

In the end, I want `rot13Reader` to apply [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) to the string that it is reading, but for now, I am just trying to create a very trivial `io.Reader` that matches the proper interface.

When I run this program, it never halts. Why? Where do I have an infinite loop?

---

Update: I tried altering the `data` splice via the for loop below, but it doesn't seem to actually alter the splice. Do I need to somehow copy over `data`?

```
package main

import (

    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (r *rot13Reader) Read(data []byte) (int, error) {
    bytesRead, err := r.r.Read(data)

    // Try to alter data... only without this for loop, text prints in standard output... odd.
    for i := 0; i < bytesRead; i++ {
        data[i] += 13   
    }

    return bytesRead, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader(
        "Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't match the interface.  It's saying that it copied 5 bytes into the slice that was passed in without error.  It did not do that.

Comment: Thank you! I think you're right. I updated my question. How do I copy data into the splice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

io.Copy calls your Read() method continuously.

From the docs:

"Copy copies from src to dst until either EOF is reached
on src or an error occurs.  It returns the number of bytes
copied and the first error encountered while copying, if any."

You need to either send EOF or return an error.

Here's an updated version that doesn't endless loop.

http://play.golang.org/p/UCfcw4S8yf

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

// Very trivial function I implemented.
func (r *rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    return 5, io.EOF // Return some trivial values for now.
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader(
        "Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
    fmt.Printf("Done copying...\n")
}
```

If you want to actually copy the string to the output.  You need to read from rot13Reader.r and copy it to p in the Read() method.

http://play.golang.org/p/dSCauz0uTw

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

// Very trivial function I implemented.
func (r *rot13Reader) Read(p []byte) (int, error) {
    i, err := r.r.Read(p)
    return i, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
    fmt.Printf("\nDone copying...\n")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sending an error makes it halt. Also, why isn't `io.Copy(os.Stout, &r)` printing the original text stored in `p`? My `io.Reader` never modified the original text, right?

Comment: You're not copying the data.  Your rot13Reader.Read() method is just returning immediately.

Comment: Ah thanks! So I must call `io.Copy(os.Stdout, r.r)` in my function. But what if I want to modify what the reader `r.r` is outputting before directly copying the data to `os.Stdout`?

Comment: Read the data.  Then modify it before returning.

Comment: Thanks! I also just realized that `len(p)` within my function is 32768. Wow! Why is that? What purpose does `p` even serve?

Comment: I think strings.NewReader is just allocating a 32k buffer even though your string isn't that long.  It can be more efficient to allocate more than you need in the event that you want to append more data.  You can look up strings.NewReader in the source and find out the specifics.

Comment: The `io.Copy` function allocates a 32K `Read` buffer: `buf := make([]byte, 32*1024)`. It doesn't know how large the buffer should be so it allocates a large buffer for efficient copying of large amounts of data. When the copy is complete, the memory for the buffer is released.